# Unexpected token ILLEGAL when insert text contain line break

Tags: jquery, text

I have piece of string like:

```
var str = "Hello // break here
World!";
```

This string is inserted into database via a textarea. When I try to display this string inside an element with:

```
$(".text").html(str);
```

It returns error `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I've already known that the line break causes this issue.

```
$(".text").html("Hello
World!");
```

How could I fix it without removing line break?

Comment: Multiline strings are not valid in Javascript

Comment: and line breaks are not shown in HTML anyway, so why do you need to keep them ?

Comment: I meant that I want to keep the text structure, actually not this line-break that causes the error.

Comment: If you want to keep the linebreak so it shows on the page, use a BR tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS doesn't let strings contain a literal linebreak in the source. If you need one for whatever reason, use `\n` or `\[literal linebreak]`. The former is preferred.